# UIWebView Youtube embed sound plays but no video shows in iOS 3.2 (iPad)

Tags: iphone, youtube

I'm using a UIWebView to display YouTube videos. It works fine on iOS 4+ but doesn't work on the iPad (iOS 3.2). The UIWebView loads as expected and displays the thumbnail of the video. When I tap on the thumbnail I see a gray quicktime icon and can hear sound but no video appears.

This is the code I'm using:

```
UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.to.video/"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];

VideoPlayerController* videoController = [[VideoPlayerController alloc] init];
[[videoController view] addSubview:webView];
UINavigationController*  theNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]

initWithRootViewController:videoController];
[self presentModalViewController:theNavController animated:YES];

[videoController release];
[theNavController release];
[webView release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with iOS 3.2 on the iPad. It will (hopefully) be fixed when iOS 4.2 is released in November.